# NSWindow, strange corner when using Core Animation

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nswindow

In my project there is a view with a custom drawRect: method which draws a dark background. When I call **[view setWantsLayer:YES]** the corner of the window (where view is placed) appears less smooth (image 2) than usual (image 1).

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `cornerRadius:` and enable `maskToBounds:` for layer like this:

```
[view setWantsLayer:YES];
[[view layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[view layer] setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

Result:

[image: Result image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @justin-boo, but the result is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G2JuY.png

Comment: @user1471997 change View's background color to black also. And use smaller cornerRadius size.